# Total number of isomers formed on monobromination of 2-methylbutane

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, chirality, halogenation

> What is the total number of isomers formed on monobromination of 2-methylbutane (including configurational and stereoisomers)?

I tried working it out. However, I found only five:

[image: 1: 1‐bromo‐2‐methylbutane; 2: 2‐bromo‐2‐methylbutane; 3: 2‐bromo‐3‐methylbutane; 4: 1‐bromo‐3‐methylbutane]

According to the source, the answer is six. Which structure am I missing?

Comment: What’s the source?

Comment: One of the online practice questions i was doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the six structures that your source is probably referencing.

[image: answer]

Comment: Oh yes! I overlooked the fact that the first structure had a chiral carbon too! Thank you very much!